# Preferred method, using Ubuntu 12.04, for copying a file from another machine without using a password

Tags: networking, copy, client-server

What do you recommend and why? [rsync](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) [scp](http://linux.die.net/man/1/scp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rsync` uses a remote shell (`rsh`, `ssh`) to do its job. It's added value over `rcp` or `scp` is that it's smart at synchronizing files: it uses the file(s) size or modification time to decide if the file(s) indeed needs to be updated, and, to quote its man page, uses a " delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by  sending  only  the  differences between  the  source files and the existing files in the destination".

`rsync` typical use case is to backup entire directory trees. This "smart files synchronization" do not seem to be part of your requirement, and as I see it if you want to copy a single file:

- `rsync` is overkill,
- ...and require to setup a remote shell anyway.

So back to the remote shell solution. Forget about `rsh`, it is to be considered deprecated since we now have `ssh`. So the solution I'd use would be `ssh` (`scp`) without password, by key setup on both systems.

Just google "ssh without password" on how to setup that, and the then use `scp`.

Comment: Thank you, the ssh with a key is the solution I used. Sorry for the late kudos.